# how delay a function when i kepress in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout, delay

I have a search place and when i enter it begin search and it's good but I want that when I press enter the function starts after 2 seconds.

I am using `setTimeout` but it doesn't work correctly.

What can I do ?

The form:

```
<form id="search" method="get">
  <input id="searchplace" type="text" size="40" value="" placeholder="xxxx" />
</form>
```

The JavaScript

```
$("#search").keypress(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $('.menu-bg').addClass('loading');      
    var x = $("#searchplace").val();

    setTimeout(m(),2000);

    function m(){
      $('.tabs').remove();
      window.location="search.php?page=noajax&q="+x;
      return false;
    };  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the handler reference to setTimout not need to call the handler. In `m()` you are redirecting to other page?

Change

```
setTimeout(m(),2000);
```

To

```
setTimeout(m,2000);
```

Also define m() outside event key press

```
var x;
$("#search").keypress(function(event){

  if(event.keyCode == 13){

     $('.menu-bg').addClass('loading');     
     x = $("#searchplace").val();
     setTimeout(m,2000);   

  }
});

function m(){
   $('.tabs').remove();
   window.location="search.php?page=noajax&q="+x;    
   return false;
};
```

Comment: `x` is being defined as a variable inside the event handler so will be undefined in the `m` function here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
setTimeout(m, 2000);
```

Without the `()`